# Shifting position of a drawable in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-edittext

Does anyone know how to shift the image of the drawable of edittext to a little left/right???

what I am getting is [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/26251665.png/)

What I want is [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/228/55310994.png/):

Comment: Please put your layout xml file here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `padding` you can do this...

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Samir. It wasted a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your xml:

`android:drawablePadding="5dip"`

For more info please refer to the [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawablePadding).